# Using bold for a selected part of text in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

In an SSRS report I separate some text in a report as:

Text 1 / Text 2

Which stems from some SQL:

SELECT  a.field1 + ' / ' + b.field2 AS [Output name]

In an ideal world I'd like a.field1 above to display in **bold** text while '/' and b.field2 remain in normal text.

So:

**Text 1** / Text 2

Is it possible to do this and if so - how would I go about doing it? Can I use an expression in SSRS or is there another clever way of doing it?

Help appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is to keep both the original text columns and then concatenate them in SSRS.

In your textbox, or tablix cell set the content to be field1 as normal, then click just after the field name and type the literal part (in your case ' / ' then finally, at the end of the literal you just type, right-click and choose `Create Placeholder`. Set the placeholder expression to be field2.

You can now format each component independently.

Here's a simple table using the above approach in the 3rd column.

[image]

The final output looks like this
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to come back to me Alan. That worked perfectly. An enormous help. Have a great day.